# How to override Doctrine @userAware annotion / filter on specific query?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I follow [this instruction](http://blog.michaelperrin.fr/2014/12/05/doctrine-filters/) to create a `@userAware` annotation which automatically limits all queries on specific entities to the current user.

For example `$todoRepo->findByTag("someTag")` will automatically add `WHERE user_id = 123` to the resulting query to make sure that only `ToDo` entities of the current user (id 123) can be accessed.

This works great but has one big downside: If for example the admin whats to know how many `ToDo` entities use the tag `someTag` he will only find his own entities...

**Since using an `@userAware` annotation seems to be quite common, I wonder if there is any best practice on how to disable/bypass/override this filter/annotation on a specific query.**

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the filter. In your example, you must change the kernel request event, like that ...

```
public function onKernelRequest()
{
    if ($user = $this->getUser()) {
        if ($user->isAdmin() /* or whatever */) {
             $this->em->getFilters()->disable('user_filter');
        } else {
             $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->enable('user_filter');
             $filter->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
             $filter->setAnnotationReader($this->reader);
        }
    }
}
```